# List modulus error

Tags: c++, list, stl, modulus

p is a list of integers.

```
std::list<int> p;
    if ( 2 % p(0) == 0 );
```

But p has "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" error.

Why?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to know if the first item of the list is even, then Dukeling's answer will handle it. If not, then you need to explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` doesn't overload `operator(int)`, this is a requirement for you to be able to say `p(0)`.

If you meant  `p[0]`, `list` doesn't overload `operator[int]` either, this is only for `vector`, `map` (or actually `operator[keyType]`), etc. This is because `list`s don't have random access (meaning you can't get any element, unless you loop through)

You can however do something like:

```
if (2 % p.front() == 0)
```

or

```
if (2 % *p.begin() == 0)
```

which accesses the first element.

Comment: I think maybe he meant to write `p[0]` to get the first element of the list. (Yes, I know that doesn't work for lists)